# Define an empty object type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm looking for ways to define an empty object type that can't hold any values.

```js
type EmptyObject = {}

const MyObject: EmptyObject = {
  thisShouldNotWork: {},
};
```

Objects with the type are free to add any properties. How can I force `MyObject` to always be an empty object instead?

My actual use case is using the EmptyObject type inside an interface.

```js
interface SchemaWithEmptyObject {
  emptyObj: EmptyObject; 
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
type EmptyObject = {
    [K in any] : never
}

const one: EmptyObject = {}; // yes ok
const two: EmptyObject = {a: 1}; // error
```

What we are saying here is that all eventual properties of our `EmptyObject` can be only `never`, and as `never` has no representing value, creating such property is not possible, therefor the object will remain empty, as this is the only way we can create it without compilation error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work when you want to discriminate against an intersection union type:


`type Union = EmptyObject | { id: string }; const a: Union = {}; const b: string = a.id // this should raise an error but does not.`

Answer (score 24):

```
type EmptyObject = Record<any, never>
```

This is equivalent to [Maciej Sikora's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60112239) but makes use of the [Record utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

Comment: Or `Record<string, never>` to avoid using an explicit any (eslint error)

Comment: Or Record<PropertyKey, never> so it supports string, number, and symbol properties.

Answer (score 8):

Acording to VSC linter `type emtyObj = Record<string, never>` .

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for defining an empty object type, and it completely depends on the side-effects you want regarding your linter and typescript errors when accessing or setting properties. These are the options I tried:

```
// Option A:
let objA: Record<any, never> = {}; // Typescript-ESLint error: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.
objA = { prop: 'value' }; // Typescript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
console.log(objA.prop);
console.log(objA.nonExistingProp); // No error!!!

// Option B:
let objB: Record<string, never> = {};
objB = { prop: 'value' }; // Typescript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
console.log(objB.prop);
console.log(objB.nonExistingProp); // No error!!!

// Option C:
let objC: Record<never, never> = {};
objC = { prop: 'value' };
console.log(objC.prop); // Typescript error: Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'Record<never, never>'
console.log(objC.nonExistingProp); // Typescript error: Property 'nonExistingProp' does not exist on type 'Record<never, never>'.
```

**TLDR: `Record<string, never>` raises errors when setting properties to the empty object. `Record<never, never>` raises errors when accessing properties of the empty object.** I have yet to find a solution that raises errors in both cases.

Personally I went with option C for my current use-case, because I wanted an error to happen if I try to access a property of an empty object, but you may not want that!

Answer (score 2):

Type-fest has a battle-tested definition of an empty object

https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/b9723d4785f01f8d2487c09ee5871a1f615781aa/source/empty-object.d.ts

```
declare const emptyObjectSymbol: unique symbol;
export type EmptyObject = {[emptyObjectSymbol]?: never};
```

---

*You can read more why other versions are problematic here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/issues/395.*

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this with a private symbol?

```
// EmptyType.ts
const EMPTY_SYMBOL = Symbol();
export type EmptyType = {[EMPTY_SYMBOL]?: never};
```

It works correctly against an intersection union type.

```
import {EmptyType} from "./EmptyType";
type Union = EmptyType | { id: string };
const a: Union = {};
const b: string = a.id; // <-- error
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEFsAcBcE8Aq9oFMB0sDOBYAUAMYD2AdlrBALIAKiAmgPoDKdlAQgPIAyoAvKE3iQARkQA2ACgCUAbnyoAHtCIAnCgjQQYCZJv4BvANrga9Zq05cAugH4AXKBKoAbqhUBfOXnwgAljFUKfSg4JBRUd1AAMxUiSFAAInRgEJ1whK8NVFAAVRJfUj4tUN1sgB9QfVBfABMHchVfEgBzUE98YjIKAEMHPIKSIv12wlJyUGF62EaWou70WplQEFAAHgBaddA3WJUgA)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).